# even after using pip update command, the version remains the same

Tags: pip

I was just trying to download packages using pip in the terminal in pycharm and there was a notice from pip saying "You are using pip version 10.0.1, however, version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

I ran the command but when I typed "pip -V" to check the version, it remained the same 10.0.1. And when I run the command, it says that pip is already up to date

How can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `python` and `pip` seem to point to different python versions. Check by typing `which python` or `where python` in the terminal.

To make sure they match, you can use

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip` (as you did) for upgrading

`python -m pip install <package name>` for installation

Comment: So how do I change?

Comment: @user12308200 That depends on your OS and the current setup that you have. Which OS are you using and what verisons of python do you have installed and where do `python` and `pip` point to in your case/

Comment: I have windows 10 and I have python 3.7 stored at ……/user/pycharmproject/venv/Scripts/python.exe and the pip version is10.0.1

Comment: and I do not know how python points to pip. Could you tell me how to change the pointer?